# Error when checking target: expected activation_1018 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 256, 256, 1)

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Снова и снова возникает ошибка: "Error when checking target: expected activation_1018 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 256, 256, 1)". Я понимаю, что проблема возникает при попытке подать в функцию активации массив большей размерности, но не могу понять, почему Reshape не решает эту проблему...

**Заранее благодарю Вас за помощь или хотя бы наводку!**

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Reshape, Permute
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import models
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import json
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = 'mode=FAST_RUN, device=gpu0, floatX=float32, optimizer=fast_compile'


img_w = 256
img_h = 256
n_labels = 1

kernel = (3, 3)


# модель SegNet

encoding_layers = [
    Conv2D(64, kernel, padding='same', input_shape=(img_h, img_w, 1)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(64, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),

    Conv2D(128, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(128, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),

    Conv2D(256, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(256, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(256, kernel, padding='same'),

    Activation('relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),

    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),

    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
]

autoencoder = models.Sequential()
autoencoder.encoding_layers = encoding_layers

for l in autoencoder.encoding_layers:
    autoencoder.add(l)
    print(l.input_shape,l.output_shape,l)

decoding_layers = [
    UpSampling2D(),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),

    UpSampling2D(),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(512, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(256, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),

    UpSampling2D(),
    Conv2D(256, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(256, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(128, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),

    UpSampling2D(),
    Conv2D(128, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(64, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),

    UpSampling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, kernel, padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    Conv2D(n_labels, (1, 1), padding='valid'),
    BatchNormalization(),
]

autoencoder.decoding_layers = decoding_layers
for l in autoencoder.decoding_layers:
    autoencoder.add(l)

autoencoder.add(Reshape((img_h * img_w, n_labels)))
#autoencoder.add(Permute((2, 1)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('softmax'))

# сохранение модели
with open('model_5l.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(json.loads(autoencoder.to_json()), indent=2))


sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005, nesterov=False)
autoencoder.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])


epochs = 5
spe = 30

data_gen_args = dict(rescale = 1./255)

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

data_IMpath = "train_images"
data_MSpath = "train_images_mask"
seed = 1
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_IMpath,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed,
    target_size = (256, 256),
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    batch_size = 1)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_MSpath,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed,
    target_size = (256, 256),
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    batch_size = 1)

train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

autoencoder.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = 15, epochs = 10)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a3f68d5b5ee9> in <module>()
----> 1 autoencoder.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = 15, epochs = 10)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1313                                         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1314                                         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1315                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1316 
   1317     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2228                     outs = self.train_on_batch(x, y,
   2229                                                sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 2230                                                class_weight=class_weight)
   2231 
   2232                     if not isinstance(outs, list):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1875             x, y,
   1876             sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1877             class_weight=class_weight)
   1878         if self.uses_learning_phase and not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int):
   1879             ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1.]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
   1478                                     output_shapes,
   1479                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1480                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1481         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1482                                                      self._feed_output_names)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    111                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    112                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 113                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    114                 if not check_batch_axis:
    115                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_26 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 256, 256, 1)
```

Архитектура

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 64)      640       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 256, 256, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 256, 256, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 128, 128, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 128, 128, 128)     512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 128, 128, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 128, 128, 128)     512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 128, 128, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 64, 64, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 64, 64, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 64, 64, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 32, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)   (None, 32, 32, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_11 (Activation)   (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)   (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)   (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_14 (Activation)   (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_15 (Activation)   (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_16 (Activation)   (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 32, 32, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (Batc (None, 32, 32, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_17 (Activation)   (None, 32, 32, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (Batc (None, 32, 32, 512)       2048      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_18 (Activation)   (None, 32, 32, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 256)       1179904   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (Batc (None, 32, 32, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_19 (Activation)   (None, 32, 32, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 64, 64, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (Batc (None, 64, 64, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_20 (Activation)   (None, 64, 64, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_20 (Batc (None, 64, 64, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_21 (Activation)   (None, 64, 64, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 128)       295040    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_21 (Batc (None, 64, 64, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_22 (Activation)   (None, 64, 64, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_4 (UpSampling2 (None, 128, 128, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_22 (Batc (None, 128, 128, 128)     512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_23 (Activation)   (None, 128, 128, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 64)      73792     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_23 (Batc (None, 128, 128, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_24 (Activation)   (None, 128, 128, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_5 (UpSampling2 (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_25 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_24 (Batc (None, 256, 256, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_25 (Activation)   (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_26 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 1)       65        
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_25 (Batc (None, 256, 256, 1)       4         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 65536, 1)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_26 (Activation)   (None, 65536, 1)          0         
=================================================================
Total params: 29,456,773
Trainable params: 29,441,411
Non-trainable params: 15,362
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: попробуйте минимальный но полный пример кода создать, который демонстрирует проблему с k.l.Reshape [mcve]

Comment: [пример для ndarray.reshape() метода](https://pastebin.com/cR0wn3hE)

Comment: Попробуйте выложить (на какой-нибудь файлообменник) небольшой пример данных, при помощи которого можно было бы воспроизвести ошибку. Еще неплохо было бы привести в вопросе вывод следующей команды: `print(autoencoder.summary())`...

Comment: Не додумался с самого начала summary выложить. 
Примеры файлов изображения и маски:        http://rgho.st/private/7njG22W2r/d70b934e9a2dc8fb7090baa7032fc7d3

Comment: Я пробовал обойтись без keras-овского трансформатора данных, написав свой - не помогло.

Comment: @jfs, я уже пробовал сокращать до 4 слоев (convolution, normal, reshape, activ) - тоже не помогло (что в принципе предсказуемо, т.к. ломается сеть только на последнем слое активации).

Answer (score 1):

Все проще, чем даже можно представить. Маска обрабатывается ImageDataGenerator  (только rescale) с теми же аргументами, что и изображение. В итоге, получается массив формы (None, 256, 256, 1), что никак не удовлетворяет выходной форме массива функции активации - (None, 65536, 1). Решение - либо удалить слой Reshape, а уже на выходе производить reshape полученного массива (минуя средства Keras), либо написать собственный трансформатор данных.